# Is Gnome 3.15 using compiz

Tags: gnome, compiz

Is Gnome 3 still using compiz?

Comment: It uses `mutter`, but [not directly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56237/does-gnome-shell-use-mutter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome-shell does not use compiz but it's own compositor like KDE, but you can use compiz with gnome-fallback I believe.

Unity is the only desktop enviroment that needs compiz, but that will change in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please clarify your last statement? Will Unity stop needing compiz in the future, or will other DEs start using it?